# XPS 15 9570 Ubuntu NvIdia driver problems (16.04.4)

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, xps

I have been trying to get Ubuntu 16.04.4 stable and running on my new XPS 15 9570 for about two weeks with no success. The farthest that I have managed is getting the OS installed in dual boot alongside windows 10. When I log in for the first time using nouveau.modeset=0 and acpi=off in the boot parameters, the gui is incredibly slow and my CPU is working at around 60-70%. This lead me to assume that there is something wrong with my Nvidia graphics card drivers (my xps has the 1050Ti), yet I have tried many things and nothing has worked.

sudo apt-get purge nvidia* (then re-installing different drivers up to 396), this causes the computer to hang on reboot and freeze at the splash screen, when manually rebooted with the power button I get stuck in a login loop.

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa, sudo apt update, sudo apt upgrade (this causes the exact same login problem)

Software and updates -> additional drivers -> using NVIDIA binary driver version -xxx (upon reboot the computer will hang, and needs to be manually shut down with the power button, when I restart it presents the same login problem)

This has been extremely frustrating, so if anyone has any ideas of how to proceed please let me know.

Comment: I have had no problems with my XPS 13 9360 with any major Ubuntu distro. Have you checked in the software manager for driver updates, through the GUI? When I installed it was all handled well by the OS without needing extra help

Comment: I have tried that and I still get stuck in the login loop and ubuntu hangs on reboot.

Comment: Why are you using 16.0.4 in particular? Can you not try 18.0.4?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem with a new XPS 15 9570. Luckily, found this on the ubuntu forums that states you need to be on a very specific kernel: 4.15.0-15. Then it just works.

See forum for the exact full script to run:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2392938&page=3

Comment: Kernel 4.15.0.18 is well ahead of 16.04.4 LTS, You may have fixed your machine following the info on that thread but it is an improper answer as this could cause other conflicts on the 16.04.4 system.  Please review the AskUbuntu [Tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) for more on interaction on this site.

Comment: But with very new hardware, always best to use newest Ubuntu release and even then may need ppa's for even more current kernel, support software & drivers. It takes a while for distributions like Ubuntu to include all the latest.